# java young gc take longer sys time than user

Tags: java, garbage-collection, pause

I'm troubled in a long service paused problem caused by young gc, one of  the gc log is:

```
2018-07-04T22:01:09.296+0800: 12677.097: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-07-04T22:01:09.297+0800: 12677.098: [ParNew: 920038K->47441K(943744K), 0.7193147 secs] 2038512K->1187779K(4089472K), 0.7204508 secs] [Times: user=0.29 sys=0.72, real=0.72 secs]
```

the pause may occur serval times in an hour, the load of server is always low, usually less than 0.1, the memory is sufficient, no swap happened, I have googled this long sys time issue, only found https://blog.gceasy.io/2016/12/11/sys-time-greater-than-user-time/
which says two reasons:

- Operating system problem
- VM related problem

but I don't think it covers all cases. because I have another java service which takes more heap running on the same server, and not suffered on this.

my system is centos 6, kernel version is 2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64 , jdk is jdk1.8.0_65, the main jvm options are:

-XX:MetaspaceSize=256M  -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M -Xms4g -Xmx4g -Xmn1g -Xss256k -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC

any suggestions? thanks!

edited:

paging log:

```
09:50:01 PM      2.36    573.77    295.95      0.04    636.73      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00  

10:00:01 PM  pgpgin/s pgpgout/s   fault/s  majflt/s  pgfree/s pgscank/s pgscand/s pgsteal/s    %vmeff

10:00:01 PM      5.39    577.19    496.32      0.08    913.33      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00

10:10:01 PM     48.39   1425.40    519.28      0.24   1060.78      0.00     18.63     18.61     99.89

10:20:01 PM      1.57   1156.95    386.99      0.02    941.61    104.35      8.11    112.41     99.96
```

and free output:

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:      65858212   64025056    1833156          0     159476   32796852

-/+ buffers/cache:   31068728   34789484

Swap:     67108860          0   67108860
```

Comment: It sure *looks* like a VM problem. Why are you so certain it's not? And have you tried running this on a modern kernel?

Comment: because we have a lot of services running on several servers with this environment,  only this service(on 3 different servers) is in trouble, the server is a physical server, not a vm. another service on this server don't have this problem.

Comment: How much memory does your box have and how much is being used by other services? This does seem odd; the high sys time shows most of the time in kernel mode, i.e. executing a system call so not JVM related. My first assumption would be the kernel struggling to get memory. Are you running something like sar to observe paging activity whilst your service is struggling? The fact that the minor GC you show recovers a lot of space doesn't really indicate a memory allocation issue. Ideally, you want to strace the process so you can see what system call(s) are causing the problem.

Comment: the total memory on server is 64G, other services used < 30G, sar log added to the origin post, but it is 10min interval. I will learn to use strace if no more hints found. thanks

Comment: sorry, I found that other services indeed suddenly consume memory much more than they usually do,  this caused the long sys time for gc, I moved my server to a new physical server, the max sys time is reduced to 0.17s, there are about 4 times sys time greater than 0.1s in a day, is it a reasonable value?